# Responsive sizing on dashbio Circos / D3 Chord Diagram

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, plotly-dash, chord-diagram, circos

Hey so I'm using [dashbio circos](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-bio/circos) which is chord diagram library built on D3's chord diagram. The circos (chord diagram) has a property called `size`, which you write a number to to set the size of the chord diagram. (If you don't set a size, then it will set a default size for you.)

However, the circos gets rendered as an svg when translated to html, and I find it difficult to give it responsive sizing. When I gave it a smaller width and height, it cuts off the circos a little. It appears that the chords and the arcs inside the circos are an absolute size, so resizing the svg will not help the diagram itself get bigger or smaller. Is it possible to give this circos responsive sizing?

I'm thinking we can change something in the underlying library to give it responsive sizing, or it's already there and I just can't find it.
Here is the link of the underlying library/github repo I'm using for dash-bio circos which is built on JS/React.js: https://github.com/plotly/dash-bio